# How to turn a TaskOption into a TaskEither using fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I have a function that can be used to find an object in the database and returns a `TaskOption`:

```
find: (key: SchemaInfo) => TO.TaskOption<Schema>
```

and another one that saves it:

```
register: (schema: Schema) => TE.TaskEither<Error, void>
```

In my `register` implementation I'd like to check whether the `Schema` I'm trying to save exists or not (I want to use `find`), but I don't know how to map a `TaskOption` into a `TaskEither`. I tried to do this:

```
pipe(
    findSchema(schema.info),
    TE.fromTaskOption,
    TE.swap
)
```

but `TE.fromTaskOption` doesn't return the `TaskEither` I expect. I also tried `TE.fromTaskOptionK` but it didn't work either, it returns a weird shaped function instead.

My use case is that in case the `TaskOption` is `none` I try saving (this means that the schema is not registered yet) otherwise I return an error (the schema is already registered). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

`TE.fromTaskOption` requires a value to put into `Left`, when the TO is `None`

Try this:

```
pipe(
    findSchema(schema.info),
    TE.fromTaskOption(() => "No schema"),
    TE.swap
)
```